# Distributing images correctly

Tags: graphics, subfloats

I'm writing this text, and I have some images which I would like to put in the text. I am using

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
```

in my preamble, so I can force the figures to stay where I want, instead of go flying. Now, I'm trying to put three images at once, but they stay in one page all together, wasting good space from the previous page. Breaking everything into two environments `figure` makes the labelling `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` go away. I want to keep this labelling. Also, removing the `[H]` does not help. What do I do?

Code:

```
\begin{figure}[H] 

\centering 

\subfloat[A aplicação de Gauss no
 $R^3$.]{\includegraphics[scale =
 0.7]{Imagens_L3/Capitulo_7/Mapa_de_Gauss_R3}}

\subfloat[A aplicação de Gauss de uma superfície tipo
 espaço]{\includegraphics[scale =
 0.7]{Imagens_L3/Capitulo_7/Mapa_de_Gauss_Sitter}}

\subfloat[A aplicação de Gauss de uma superfície tipo
 tempo.]{\includegraphics[scale =
 0.7]{Imagens_L3/Capitulo_7/Mapa_de_Gauss_PH}}

\end{figure}
```

How it is now:

[image]

Comment: You need `\ContinuedFloat` from `caption` package, I hope.

Comment: Well I'm working with figures and having similar troubles I found better results using _heavy weapons_ instead the `float` and `subfig` packages. I use the `standalone`class for get the arrangements of figures that I need using inside the `table` or `array` environments. Finally the packages `afterpage`and `placeins`let me get better control of the float images. I don't know if this can help you. Try to improve your question with a complete MWE.

Comment: What do you want? All thee pictures on one page or seperate pictures on seperate pages? If it's in one figure environment then it's a float (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) and the float object will stay together.

Comment: Instead of `subfig`, try `subcaption`. It works much better with package  `hyperref`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\ContinuedFloat` from `caption` package and for subfigures, use `subcaption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{continued}{#1~#2 (Cont.)}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=continued}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Some figure and its caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
        \caption{}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Some figure and its caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I read before that you should not use the package `caption`together with `subfig`, you have to choose one of both, and in this case `caption` allows good results.

Comment: @Aradnix Not exactly. For details, see the section 4.1 of `subfig` manual. :-)

Comment: @Harish `\ContinuedFloat` did what I wanted, thanks. I couldn't use the packages `subfig` and `subcaption` at the same time, though. I kept `subfig` since I've got so many other imagens in the text, and it would be too much trouble adjusting everything. The packages `subfig` and `caption` do work together. Any thoughts?

Comment: @IvoTerek They do work together. But in future, it is better to use `subcaption` as there are places where `subfig` may not be compatible.

Comment: Weird. I got a warning saying that they don't, here. Well, I'll worry about that when I need to. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @IvoTerek Sorry. I wrote the above for `caption` and `subfig`. `subcaption` and `subfig` aren't comfortable with each other.

Comment: Ah! Not weird then. `:)`